# Transform double for Loop to Stream?

Tags: java, for-loop, replace, java-stream

I'm just curious if i can switch this

```
 for (String arg : args) {
        int number = Integer.parseInt(arg);
        int checksum = 0;

        for (int digits = 0; digits < 10; digits++) {
            checksum += number % 10;
            number /= 10;
        }
        System.out.println(checksum);
    }
}
```

into a piped Java Stream (only that condition, no recursive method etc.).

My first attempt was

```
    public static void main(String... args) {
    Stream.of(args)
            .?
    }
```

with then somehow use a function like:

```
class FunctionTest implements Function<String, Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer apply(String s) {
        int number = Integer.parseInt(s);
        int checksum = 0;

        IntStream.range(1,10).reduce(number, ()-> ?)

            checksum += number % 10;
            number /= 10;

        return checksum;
    }
}
```

But I guess I come to a dead end with that...

Does someone has a better idea or is it actually impossible?

Comment: It that reduction supposed to sum the first 10 digits of the number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Arrays.stream(args)
      .map(Integer::parseInt)
      .map(number -> {
          int sum = 0;
          for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
              sum += number % 10;
              number /= 10;
          }
          return sum;
      })
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Or alternatively (**note** this would **not** work for negative numbers):

```
Arrays.stream(args)
      .map(number -> number.split(""))
      .map(Arrays::stream)
      .map(strStream -> strStream.mapToInt(Integer::parseInt))
      .map(IntStream::sum)
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

This one splits the string into its individual character strings, maps them to integers and then sums them

And finally, also a positive number only solution:

```
 Arrays.stream(args)
       .map(CharSequence::chars)
       .map(chars -> chars.map(Character::getNumericValue))
       .map(IntStream::sum)
       .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: your alternative looks very good (in my example i just use positve numbers)
Thank you!

Comment: `.split("(?!^)")` looks like a convoluted variant of `.split("")`. But in the end, it’s [even simpler](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38186913/2711488)…

Comment: @Holger Yes you are right, thanks for pointing that out. I have simplified it to just `split("")`.

Answer (score 3):

### **An approach assuming input are Strings**

This is somewhat obscure due to the fact there is only `IntStream`, but no `CharStream`. [CharSequence.chars()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#chars--) gives an IntStream. `'0'` maps to `48` according to ASCII, `'1'` to `49` etc. So you can just subtract 48 to get the int value.

```
 String[]x={"1495","34","333333","-13"};
 Arrays.stream(x)
      .map(y-> y.chars().map(z->z-48).sum()) 
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

As pointed out by JBNizet, that solution does not do exactly the same thing. It does not throw an exception if any of the strings are not Integers (and works for Strings representing integers larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`).
Also, it returns a positive sum for negative numbers (for which the `-` sign should probably filtered, for example with `.filter(Character::isDigit)`

### Another approach assuming input are Integers

This more like a "translation" of OP's code to [`IntStream.generate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#generate-java.util.function.IntSupplier-). The stream starts with the original integer and subsequent elements are generated by division by 10. The, the elements are mapped to modulo by 10.

```
    int[]ints={1495,34,333333,-13};
    IntStream.of(ints)
            .map( a-> IntStream.iterate(a,b->b/10) // (1)
                            .map(c->c%10) // (2)
                            .limit(10) // (3)
                            .sum())
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

(1) for example generates for 1495 the following IntStream:

> 1495 149 14 1 0 0 ...

(2) map to modulo:

> 5 9 4 1 0 0 ...

(3) since this is an infinite stream, we need a limit

Comment: `Character::getNumericValue` would be more self-explanatory.

Comment: But both solutions don't do the same thing as what the OP does (no validation that the string is an integer), and give different results for negative integers.

Comment: @JBNizet It turns out the numeric value of a `-` is -1 (or -3 if using the subtraction method), so the answer would only be off by one. Perhaps run the string through a `.map(s -> s.replaceAll("\\D+",""))` initially?

Comment: Don't use a regex when you don't need one. All you would need is `filter(z -> z != '-')` before the map.

Comment: But anyway, I have the feeling that the checksum algorithm is supposed to checksum integers. The fact that the program starts with Strings and parses them is, to me, anecdotal. So I would still prefer a checksum() method which deals with integers rather than Strings.

Comment: To make myself clearer, I read the question as: "I have a checksum algorithms that work on integers, and I have an array of Strings representing integers. How do I apply this algorithm on all the strings?".

Comment: @JBNizet: added an 'integer' solution

Comment: Well the String appears from String...args in the Main where i read the command line from. Actually i work only with Integers.

Comment: @N-rG: well then the second approach is probably better. if you also want to replace the calculation of the sum with a Stream, you can use the `IntStream.iterate(a,b->b/10).map(c->c%10).limit(10).sum()` approach.

Answer (score 3):

Note that not only arrays and collections are streamable, character sequences are as well. Now, you *can* stream over the characters and convert each digit to a numerical value before summing, but the conversion only implies subtracting the same offset (`'0'`) from the character and there is already a basic arithmetic solution for summing the same number a number of times, the multiplication:

```
Arrays.stream(args)
      .map(s -> s.chars().sum()-'0'*s.length())
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

This is concise and efficient.

In case you need support for negative numbers, you can change it to

```
Arrays.stream(args)
      .map(s -> s.startsWith("-")?
                '0'*(s.length()-1)-s.chars().skip(1).sum():
                s.chars().sum()-'0'*s.length())
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 2):

The checksum computation is not a good candidate for a stream-based solution, IMO. The loop through the arguments can be transformed to streams, though:

```
public class Help {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Arrays.stream(args)
              .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
              .map(Help::toCheckSum)
              .forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static int toCheckSum(int number) {
        int checksum = 0;

        for (int digits = 0; digits < 10; digits++) {
            checksum += number % 10;
            number /= 10;
        }

        return checksum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is using a helper function more efficient than using a lambda? I like this because it's reusable.

Comment: Is *what* more efficient? Using which lambda?

Comment: I clarified the comment. I'm asking how this compares with @arizzle

Comment: No, it would be as efficient. Extracting the code to a named method makes the code more readable and more testable, though.

Comment: Well the helper function is kinda cheating cause i still use a for loop ;)

Comment: Using a loop is not cheating. If the code is clearer, easier to write, read and understand with a loop, then a loop is the good thing to use.

Comment: Yes, and I clearly said No to saying No to loops. So what?

Comment: Why you offer a soloution to a problem which includes the problem. Well luckily here are some professionals who could read and offer a proper solution, so it doesnt really matter what you write :)

Comment: Professionals use the right tool for the job, and provide arguments about their design choice. They favor readability over "coolness" (whatever that means). They don't use streams everywhere without thinking just because it's the new thing. They challenge their requirements when they aren't correct. You will realize that when you become one.

Comment: Your code is not easier to read/write or to understand. Moreover its nearly triple as long as:

Arrays.stream(args)
      .map(number -> number.split("(?!^)"))
      .map(Arrays::stream)
      .map(strStream -> strStream.mapToInt(Integer::parseInt))
      .map(IntStream::sum)
      .forEach(System.out::println);

When its easier for you, its okay. But i dont want long unnecessary code and prefer to use the advance of modern languages.

Comment: @N-rG: If you want a short solution, you could try mine. But the foremost limitation of the quoted solution are: it uses a regex to split a String, which is 1. obscure, 2. probably inefficient.